# While count in python

Tags: python, loops, count, while-loop

```
user_answer = (raw_input('Can you guess the word that is missing? ')).lower()
count =0
while count <=1:
     if user_answer == 'brown':
          print ('Well done')
          break
     else:
          user_answer =(raw_input('Please Guess again? '))
          count+=1
else:
     print ("Fail Game")
```

I'm working on a simple game and it allows the user to input the wrong guess three times. I have been playing around with this while loop and it works, (while count <=1) but i am a little confused as too why??? (not complaining) but can anyone explain why it works as i originally though the code should be like to one below (but these uses 5 attempts)

```
count = 0
while count <=3:
```

all rest of code is same as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of inputs you can get with that code is `3`. **Why?**

- The first is outside the loop.
- The second is when `count` is `0`. After the input, `count` will be `1`.
- The third (and last) is when `count` is `1`. After the input, `count` will be `2`. The loop will finish in the next iteration because the condition `2 <= 1` will be `False`.

Comment: i didn't think about the 1st instance of the first one outside the loop. Makes sense now.